# error sending data url github using trufflehog tools in node js

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");
const fs = require("fs");

// Set the temporary directory to a subdirectory in your user's home directory

async function detectCredentials(url) {
  try {
    const command = `trufflehog --regex --entropy False ${url}`;
    const { stdout, stderr } = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
          return;
        }
        resolve({ stdout, stderr });
      });
    });

    if (stderr) {
      throw new Error(stderr);
    }

    const credentials = JSON.parse(stdout);

    if (credentials && credentials.matches && credentials.matches.length > 0) {
      const output = {
        detectorType: "Trufflehog",
        decoderType: "PLAIN",
        rawResult: credentials,
        line: 0,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace("T", " "),
        message: `Found credentials using Trufflehog`,
      };
```

my controller exec command line using child process

```
      // Insert output into database
      const date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace("T", " "); // Convert to MySQL datetime format
      fs.appendFileSync("result_repo.txt", `${date} ${JSON.stringify(output)}\n`);

      return output;
    } else {
      return {
        data: {
          url,
          message: "No credentials found.",
        },
      };
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      url,
      error: error.message,
    };
  }
}

module.exports = {
  detectCredentials,
};


{
    "url": "https://github.com/trufflesecurity/test_keys",
    "error": "Command failed: trufflehog --regex --entropy False https://github.com/trufflesecurity/test_keys\nTraceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\shutil.py\", line 620, in _rmtree_unsafe\r\n    os.unlink(fullname)\r\nPermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\\\Users\\\\ASUS\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\tmprwv07hp5\\\\.git\\\\objects\\\\pack\\\\pack-a2bda5bf10ab9d2ee79ac69c3b42b50666521f86.idx'\r\n\r\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\r\n\r\nTraceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"<frozen runpy>\", line 198, in _run_module_as_main\r\n  File \"<frozen runpy>\", line 88, in _run_code\r\n  File \"C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Scripts\\trufflehog.exe\\__main__.py\", line 7, in <module>\r\n  File \"C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\truffleHog\\truffleHog.py\", line 92, in main\r\n    output = find_strings(args.git_url, args.since_commit, args.max_depth, args.output_json, args.do_regex, do_entropy,\r\n             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\r\n  File \"C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\truffleHog\\truffleHog.py\", line 381, in find_strings\r\n    shutil.rmtree(project_path, onerror=del_rw)\r\n  File \"C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\shutil.py\", line 759, in rmtree\r\n    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)\r\n           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\r\n  File \"C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\shutil.py\", line 617, in _rmtree_unsafe\r\n    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)\r\n  File \"C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\shutil.py\", line 617, in _rmtree_unsafe\r\n    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)\r\n  File \"C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\shutil.py\", line 617, in _rmtree_unsafe\r\n    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)\r\n  File \"C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\shutil.py\", line 622, in _rmtree_unsafe\r\n    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())\r\n  File \"C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\truffleHog\\truffleHog.py\", line 125, in del_rw\r\n    os.remove(name)\r\nPermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\\\Users\\\\ASUS\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\tmprwv07hp5\\\\.git\\\\objects\\\\pack\\\\pack-a2bda5bf10ab9d2ee79ac69c3b42b50666521f86.idx'\r\n"
}
```

error or rather access denied which resulted in my trufflehog execution not running, if any of my friends know how to solve this, please really help, I really appreciate your help, and if you ask what this trufflehog is? this is a tool to detect private keys on repostiro